# getResourceName() returns wrong name

Tags: android, junit

I'm trying to run JUnit tests for an Android Library. So I created a new Android Application project in Eclipse, but without any Activities. I then changed the AndroidManifest.xml so that it uses the instrumentation of "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner", and also added

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

Next, I added my Android Library to the library references in the project properties.

My problem is that I want to use Resources from the test project to drive tests on the library. For example, I added a "hello_world" text file to the res/raw folder in the test project.

This resource now shows up in R.raw.hello_world

The problem is that when I call context.getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.hello_world) it's returning the wrong name. It's the name of a resource in the Library that I'm trying to test.

It seems like the Resources from my test project are missing when the tests are run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the wrong context was being used.

I was using the AndroidTestCase class and the getContext() method, but that context didn't contain the resources packaged with the tests. So changing the class to InstrumentationTestCase and using getInstrumentation().getContext() solved the problem.